# Why does <lightning:radioGroup returns String rather than Boolean

Tags: javascript, lightning, radio-button

I am getting a `String` value of `'true'` from the `<lightning:radioGroup` when I expect to get a `Boolean` value of `true`

**Component**

```
<aura:component >

<aura:attribute name="booleanOptions" type="List" default="[
                {'label': 'Yes', 'value': true},
                {'label': 'No', 'value': false}
                ]"/>

<aura:attribute name="model" type="Object" />

<lightning:radioGroup
                      aura:id="radioGrp"
                      name="radioButtonGroup"
                      label="Choose Your Option"
                      options="{! v.booleanOptions }"
                      value="{! v.model.booleanValue }"
                      onchange="{! c.handleChange }"
                      />
```

The values in `booleanOptions` are `Boolean`

**Controller**

```
handleChange : function(component, event, helper) {
    var radioValue = component.get("v.model.booleanValue");
    console.log(typeof radioValue); 
}
```

This method outputs to the console:

> String

But the Salesforce Lightning documentation says that the `value` attribute/property of a `<lightning:radioGroup` is of type `object`

So why does this example return a `String` when it's given `Boolean` options.

This is an issue because I keep needing to do this to handle it:

```
<aura:if isTrue="{!or(v.model.booleanValue == 'true', v.model.booleanValue == true) }">
     // some content
</aura:if>
```

Which just does **not** seem right.

Reference:

- [Salesforce Lightning RadioGroup Specification](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:radioGroup/specification)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the [HTML specification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio) says that "value" is a "String." You need to convert it to a Boolean value if you want it as a Boolean. I know it's kind of a silly rule, but you have to remember that it's meant to be used in a way that any sort of value could come out of it:

```
<input type="radio" value="Mango" name="fruit" />
<input type="radio" value="Orange" name="fruit" />
<input type="radio" value="Apple" name="fruit" />
```

In normal HTML, whichever fruit was selected would be sent to the server like this:

```
fruit=Apple
```

As such, your value is always going to be coerced back to a String, because HTML demands it. You'll need to parse it yourself, something like:

```
radioValue = radioValue == "true"
```

To convert `Boolean` object properties use this code:

```
castBooleanPropertiesToString : function(object) {

    var props = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(object);

    for (var i = 0; i < props.length; i++) {
        var propName = props[i];

        if (typeof object[propName] == 'boolean'){
            object[propName] = object[propName].toString();    
        }
    }
},
```

Comment: OK, so the Salesforce documentation is also wrong.

Comment: @Robs How so? In the documentation, they're clearly using string values.

Comment: How would I cleanly parse `v.model.booleanValue` to a Boolean inside an `<aura:if` ?

Comment: because the Salesforce documentation says that `value` is of type `object` ?

Comment: @Robs Yeah... in the documentation tab, they use String values, but I see the specification does say "object". That's also unfortunate, because `<aura:attribute type="object"` actually always gets parsed as a String (as mentioned in [this tweet](https://twitter.com/GrayJustise/status/1005567360835584000)), which is why it behaves as it does. Long story short, you'll probably want to `map` your Boolean values to String values, and always use the String values.